# Prevent loosing files when updating an IotEdge module

Tags: docker, azure-iot-edge

I have implemented an azure iotedge module that saves files to disc.
Everytime I update to a new version of my module, all files saved until then are lost.  How can I update my module and still keep the old files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default files are saved to the docker container of the module.  If you update the module, a new docker container is created and the old one including your files is discarded.

If you want to keep your files, you have to save them outside the docker container.
To do this, you have to bind a folder of the host to your module's container.

You can do that by setting the createOptions of your module in the deployment template like this:

```
"createOptions": {
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/path/on/host/:/app/files/"
         ]
     }
 }
```

If you save a file to **"./files/myfile.txt"** within your module, it will actually be saved to **"/path/on/host/myfile.txt"** on the machine hosting the docker container of your module and it will still be there after updating the module.

Before starting the module, you manually have to create the folder on the host. 
And you have to provide the moduleUser with read/write access. You can do so with:

> sudo chown 1000 /path/on/host

and then

> sudo chmod u+rw /path/on/host

Note: Since the users of the other iotedge docker containers also have UID 1000, they will also have access to that folder. The same is true for the first non-root user of the host (which usually also has the UID 1000).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to go from Windows to Windows, you can do something like this:

```
"createOptions": {
"HostConfig": {
    "Binds": [
        "C:\Temp\output:C:\app\files\"
     ]
 }
```

}

What I haven't figured out yet is how to go from windows to linux.